# Trouble with .remove() when updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to have something updated via using `setInterval(updateAngle,10);` and an `updateAngle` function where I call `canvas.remove(n)` (where canvas is a Raphael) for three differents *n*s, and then make new instances of those *n*s. I now get errors that `canvas.path()` is undefined, which I don't get if I don't make the `remove` calls. Why am I probably getting this error, and am I even doing this the right way?

EDIT: Here's the context.

```
function updateAngle(){
  // canvas.remove(initBeam);
  // canvas.remove(reflBeam);
  canvas.remove(propBeam);
  angle = angleSlider.val;
```

(17 lines later)

```
  emitter = canvas.path(makePathForPolygon([emitter_left,emitter_top,emitter_right,emitter_bottom])) // <- this errors
              .attr({'fill':EMITTER_COLOR})
              .attr({'id':'emitter'});
```

(...)

```
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted more code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found what was wrong. What I wanted was `[element].remove()`. Calling `remove()` on the canvas removes the canvas instead of the element, which is why it no longer understood `canvas`.